# Multiple subscriptions in AWS AppSync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

Similar to eugenekr back in March ([question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312173/multiple-subscriptions-in-aws-amplify-react-connect-component)) I'm having trouble setting up more than one subscription for a Todo list. I have a creation subscription and a deletion subscription, both of which work when applied individually, so that's encouraging.

If I follow mnishiguchi's suggestion and write multiple `<Connect />` components I still can't get it to work. As far as I can tell, the subscription `<Connect>`s don't actually receive anything in `prev` to operate on. Records are still added and removed from the list.

This code works (the list updates when a new Todo is added);

```
render() {
    return (
      <Segment>
        <Connect
          query={graphqlOperation(ListTodos)}
          subscription={graphqlOperation(SubscribeToNewTodos)}
          onSubscriptionMsg={this.onNewTodo}
        >
          {({ data, loading, errors }) => {
            if (loading) {
              return <div>Loading...</div>;
            }
            if (errors.length > 0) {
              return <div>{JSON.stringify(errors)}</div>;
            }
            if (!data.listTodos) return;

            return <TodosList todos={data.listTodos.items} />;
          }}
        </Connect>
      </Segment>
    );
  }
```

but if I get nothing at all if I switch to this;

```
render() {
    return (
      <Segment>
        <Connect query={graphqlOperation(ListTodos)}>
          {({ data, loading, errors }) => {
            if (loading) {
              return <div>Loading...</div>;
            }
            if (errors.length > 0) {
              return <div>{JSON.stringify(errors)}</div>;
            }
            if (!data.listTodos) return;

            return <TodosList todos={data.listTodos.items} />;
          }}
        </Connect>

        <Connect subscription={graphqlOperation(SubscribeToNewTodos)} onSubscriptionMsg={this.onNewTodo}>
          {() => {}}
        </Connect>

        <Connect subscription={graphqlOperation(SubscribeToDeleteTodos)} onSubscriptionMsg={this.onDeleteTodo}>
          {() => {}}
        </Connect>
      </Segment>
    );
  }
```

Suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.